# How to get console dom tree element value

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, dom, history.js

I am using firebug. When I load the page, I need some data from DOM.

[image]

Its my firebug `DOM` structure.
Here how can I get `wrappedData` details.

What I was trying is

```
var State = History.getState();
console.log(State.data.wrapperData);
```

Here I got output as "undefined".

I want get details from `wrapperData.name` and store in to some variable.

Thanks for advise.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a simple typo... Try:

```
console.log(State.data.wrappedData)
```

instead of

```
console.log(State.data.wrapperData);
```